# Constructing routing lines for large tree structure using the ancestry gem

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, treeview, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem and have followed the railscasts episode [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) to get the gem to work, which works perfectly.

I have created a fairly large ancestry tree, and although the parents and children are nested by indenting the fields, i prefer some sort of routing lines. The picture below show the small part of the total tree.

[image]

**I would like to have a structure look like this/ or something similar**

[image]

I tried to play around with the structure by adding lines, but i just seem to end up in smoke.

Each parent and child is given a separate div field like this(in a helper). just like the railscasts episode.

```
def nested_messages(messages)
  messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
    render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_routes(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

How can this be done, if possible. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not try to create lines using div and css tricks.  You are trying to build an element of a UI like a navigation tree.  Just go all in on a real UI library like jsTree.  Use rails to create the data structure (you've already done this), render a static HTML `<ul>` list (this should be easy to convert your `<div>`s to list elements).  Then let javascript render the view of that data structure (lines etc) and you'll get interactivity and other stuff for free.  :)

Here's the main site:
http://www.jstree.com/

Check out this demo:
http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#demos

Look at the source of the page and you'll see `<div id="demo2" ...>` where the magic starts happening.

Installing JQuery and this plugin should be fairly easy in Rails 3 (in 3.1 you already have JQuery).

Comment: thanks for the lead. I will try it out and see if it ties in with the ancestry gem i am using. Will leave question open for a few days to see if anyone else wants to post anything.

Comment: thanks, after playing around with it i managed to get it to work. thanks alot